# limit exceeded cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase as my db in a web app. today I got an error says Error: [cloud_firestore/resource-exhausted] Quota exceeded. daily limit is 50k I used that yesterday but I didn't used todays quota. Can anyone please explain how it works. I don't know what to do next

[image]